# Configure raspberry pi kernel from script instead of menuconfig

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, arm, real-time

I would like to build the official kernel for the Raspberry Pi. But I want to change one feature during the process.
I'm basically following this tutorial: http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203

And at some point it says you should run `make menuconfig` which opens a menu that you can navigate to select/change the features that you want for the kernel. I would like to set `Kernel Features → Preemption Model` to `Fully Preemptible Kernel (RT)`, but I don't want to do it manually, I would like to do this with a bash script.

I can't just do it manually once and then copy the resulting config file because when a new kernel is released, the config file might not be valid anymore. So I always want to have the default features for the current kernel + the one modification.

When I generate the default config and the customized config and compare the too, I get this result:

```
-CONFIG_TREE_RCU=y 
+CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
-# CONFIG_TASKS_RCU is not set
+CONFIG_TASKS_RCU=y
-# CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED is not set
-CONFIG_SLUB_CPU_PARTIAL=y
-CONFIG_OPROFILE=m
-CONFIG_JUMP_LABEL=y
-# CONFIG_STATIC_KEYS_SELFTEST is not set
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_JUMP_LABEL=y
-CONFIG_INLINE_SPIN_UNLOCK_IRQ=y        
-CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK=y        
-CONFIG_INLINE_READ_UNLOCK_IRQ=y        
-CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK=y       
-CONFIG_INLINE_WRITE_UNLOCK_IRQ=y
-CONFIG_MUTEX_SPIN_ON_OWNER=y       
-CONFIG_RWSEM_SPIN_ON_OWNER=y       
-CONFIG_LOCK_SPIN_ON_OWNER=y
+CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
+CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_BASE=y
+CONFIG_PREEMPT_LAZY=y
-CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y
+# CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY is not set
-# CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL is not set
+CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
+CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
-CONFIG_NET_RX_BUSY_POLL=y
-CONFIG_BCACHE=m        
-# CONFIG_BCACHE_DEBUG is not set       
-# CONFIG_BCACHE_CLOSURES_DEBUG is not set
-CONFIG_LEDS_TRIGGER_CPU=y
+CONFIG_DEBUG_PREEMPT=y
-# CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCKING_API_SELFTESTS is not set
-CONFIG_RING_BUFFER_ALLOW_SWAP=y
+# CONFIG_PREEMPT_TRACER is not set
```

Comment: Can you 1) save a copy of the default config, 2) run `make menuconfig` and change the option you're interested in, then 3) run this command to compare the two: `diff config.original config.new` and post the result of the diff?  You need to make sure that adjusting that config option doesn't have any side effects.

Comment: @AndyDalton I added the relevant information to the post. I can't post the whole thing because it's over 8000 lines.

Comment: The diff is over 8000 lines?  Seems like more than just that option is getting tweaked.  Can you do: 1) take the original default config, 2) run `make oldconfig` (you can probably give the default answer for any questions), 3.) save the new config, 4.) run `make menuconfig` and change the option you're interested in, then 5) post the output of `diff config.postoldconfig config.new`